# what does the statement "band limited signal of 5 KHz" mean

Tags: signal-analysis, bandpass, bandwidth

> A band limited signal of $5$ kHz is observed at the output node whose sampling frequency is $600$ kHz. What is the minimum order of the filter?

Does it mean:

1. a signal that is from $0$ to $5$ kHz on the frequency axis when drawn
2. a signal from $-2.5$ kHz to $2.5$ kHz
3. a signal with bandwidth of $5$ kHz centered anywhere

Comment: What is the context?  Otherwise those exact words alone seem ambiguous.

Answer (score 1):

The nature of the words in the question is slightly ambiguous.

- A Band-limited signal of bandwidth 5Khz means that the signal can be centered at any frequency but its extent around that frequency is 5Khz.
- A Band-limited signal of 5Khz is also used to represent a signal which is having a center frequency of 5Khz but which has a fixed band-width.
- It surely does not mean -2.5 to 2.5 because when mentioning the band-width usually the positive frequencies alone are counted.

I would advice you to revisit the text and look with respect to the above points.

Comment: In communications, the last point is quite likely. Many people are confused at first when signals of 20MHz bandwidth are sampled with much less than 40MHz sampling rate.

Comment: @jan You are referring to case of bandpass sampling right.

Answer (score 0):

**Choice-1** : May be for real signals but wrong for complex signals. It's better to state it as; from $-5$ kHz to $5$ kHz baseband signal.

**Choice-2** : Is **wrong** for **real** signals but may be for **complex** signals. Since a real signal with  a frequency spectrum extending from $-2.5$ kHz to $2.5$ kHz is a baseband signal with a bandwidth of $2.5$ kHz by definition which is the max positive frequency for baseband (extending from -W to +W) **real** signals. If that was a complex signal, however, then its total bandwidth could be $5$ kHz in that case (extending from $-2.5$ kHz to $2.5$ kHz.)

**Choice-3** : This can be true both for real and complex signals.

So, the statement is clearly missing necessary information and can be understood in multiple ways.

Answer (score 0):

Most likely this is a baseband signal with frequency content from 0 to 5 kHz. Although a sampling frequency of 600 kHz seems out of scale in that case.

Answer (score 0):

All the stuff about the filter and its order, and the sampling frequency,  is apparently out of scope of the question: "what does the statement “band limited signal of 5 KHz” mean" and the three-fold choice.

The first options induce assumptions not present in the text:

- a signal that is from 0 to 5 kHz on the frequency axis when drawn
- a signal from -2.5 to 2.5

So according to the Holmes principle:

> Once you eliminate the impossible, whatever remains, no matter how
>   improbable, must be the truth.

we are left with:

- a signal with bandwidth of 5 kHz centered anywhere